# how to make setup file

Tags: java, deployment, installation

i have made an application using java....my source is in .java file ...now i want to create a setup file from these source files....

so can anyone tell me how i can make this setup files like another softwares...like device driver....etc...
please co-operate me....

Answer (score 1):

Java can only be run on a machine with a JRE (Java Runtime Environment), so your setup file won't run quite the same as other application setup files; you won't be able to give someone your setup file and expect it to run correctly, unless they already have the appropriate JRE.

However, in Java, the usual way to do the "setup routine" is typically going to result in a "jar" file. Have a look at jar.exe (or "jar" if in linux/unix). It will chunk your classes into the appropriate container.

Comment: ya i got u...now i want to run my application as service/in background....so it is not showing in task manager->applications.
even though it is running....?
can u tell me...?

Comment: it's running under "java.exe" :)

Answer (score 1):

[AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/features.html) offers features for installation of [Java applications](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068) will help you.